# Java - Regex String replacement

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace some parts of a String with Regex. It's the `192001Z` part of the string I want to replace.

**Code**:

```
String met = "192001Z 17006KT 150V210 CAVOK 11/07 Q1004 NOSIG";
String regexZ = "[0-9].{5}Z";
met = met.replaceAll(regexZ, "${.now?string(\"ddHHmm\")}Z");
```

I get an error when I want to replace a part of the String with `${.now?string(\"ddHHmm\")}Z`.

But when I e.g. replace `${.now?string(\"ddHHmm\")}Z` with `ThisNeedsToBeReplaced` everything works just fine. So my guess is that something is wrong with the string I want to use to replace parts of my original string (met).

The error I receive is `Illegal group reference`.

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong with `${.now?string(\"ddHHmm\")}Z`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use:

```
met = met.replaceAll("\\b\\d{6}Z\\b", "\\${.now?string(\"ddHHmm\")}Z");
```

- Correct regex to match `192001Z` is `\b\d{6}Z\b`
- You need to escape `$` in replacement as well otherwise it is considered a back reference e.g. `$1, $2` etx.

Comment: Shouldn't `.` be escaped as well?

Comment: yep, escaping the `$` will do the job.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: DOT has no special meaning in replacement but `$` does have.

Comment: Escaping the $ did the job! Thanks!!